# org -captue template display a fake board

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

After I updated doom-emacs, the todo captuer template board displayed as

[image]

It's actually a fake board because I custom them as

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("n" "Personal Note" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/todo.today.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-personal-notes-headline)
         "* %T %?")
        ("t" "Personal Todo" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/todo.today.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-personal-tasks-headline) "* TODO %i%?")

        ("pn" "Project Note" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/todo.today.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-project-notes-headline)
         "* %T %?")
        ("pt" "Project Todo" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/todo.today.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-project-tasks-headline) "* TODO %i%?")


        ("T" "Tickler" entry
         (file+headline "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/src/tickler.org" "Tickler") "* %i%? \n %U")))
```

So when I dispatch `pt`, it invoke 'project doto`rather than 'personal todo`

Where could configure the board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting is incorrect, `C-h v org-capture-templates`:

> When using several keys, keys using the same prefix key must be
>   together in the list and preceded by a 2-element entry explaining the
>   prefix key, for example
>
> ```
> ("b" "Templates for marking stuff to buy")
> ```

so you need to put something like `("p" "Project Tasks")` right before your "pn" template, for example,

```el
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("p" "Project Tasks")
        ("pn" "Project Note")
        ("pt" "Project Todo")))
```